# Page Numbering and Definitions

Tags: indexing

I am writing a math book and at the end I want to include a list of definitions with a page number corresponding to the number it is on. I am using`\documentclass{amsart}` to start the document.

Here is an example of what I am wanting to do:
I have writing and code ... jfkdjalsdkjf... and then I have a definition: a **set** is defined as a collection of objects. Then, thirty pages later I have another definition. More code...  a number j said to be **even** if and only if j equals 2n for some integer n. So, I have all these definitions here.

---

It would be fantastic if I could just have a list of definitions/index at the end of the document which would be like [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=paINAXYHN8kC&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=Ethan%20bloch%20an%20introduction%20to%20abstract%20algebra&source=bl&ots=Fvo564sLWU&sig=HguHWnE12iNaeGjoeVfsnH2tQ0o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA-YKvt-LWAhXJCJoKHZvvCA8Q6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=Ethan%20bloch%20an%20introduction%20to%20abstract%20algebra&f=false) (page 327) without having to go through and find the page number for every definition and rewrite it in alphabetical order.

Does anyone know how I can create an index like this for the documentclass I am using? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I started writing the glossary like this but nothing seems to be working that I find online.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\begin{document}
```

Then, I have writing `\Gls{set}` ... `\Gls{even}`...

```
\clearpage
\printglossary[title={List of Symbols}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this you can have a look at the `glossaries` package. It is capable of sorting entries alphabetically, can print the corresponding page numbers (including hyperlinks when used in combination with `hyperref`) and offers a variety of different styles.

Comment: @leandriis I have been trying to figure out how to write it, but nothing seems to be working. Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I have tried to use something like makeglossaries as well, and I feel as though I am stuck. I added a little more to the question at the bottom to see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `sample-index.tex` file? It is a MWE that shows the proper use of the `glossaries` package to create an index. Information on how to compile can be found in `glossaries`' user manual in section 1.2 sample documents (page 35 for the above mentioned file).

Comment: @leandriis I figured it out here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Indices. I am not sure what an MWE is or how to go to the sample-index.tex file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A MWE is a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The sample files can be found in the  `samples` subdirectory of the `glossaries` package's documentation directory (where the manual is) but you can also find the on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples).